# ASOF JOIN is joining too much in the past

Tags: questdb, asof-join

I want to join to tables by timestamp. At the moment timestamps are aligned, but at some point in the future they might be slightly unaligned. I can use questdb `AS OF JOIN`, but this will join each row with the row matching exact timestamp or with the closest earlier timestamp on the second table. I would like to have a limit, and join only within a particular date. This is what I have so far.

```sql
SELECT inverter_1.timestamp,
avg(inverter_1.ac_power) AS "Inverter 1",
avg(inverter_4.ac_power)
FROM inverter_1 
ASOF JOIN inverter_4 WHERE inverter_1.timestamp BETWEEN '2024-01-17T00:29:15.051Z' AND '2024-01-17T00:30:15.051Z'
SAMPLE BY 1s;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I can limit how much I want to go in the past for the second table before doing the `ASOF JOIN`

```sql
SELECT inverter_1.timestamp,
avg(inverter_1.ac_power) AS "Inverter 1",
avg(inverter_4.ac_power)
FROM inverter_1 
ASOF JOIN (inverter_4 where timestamp BETWEEN '2024-01-17T00:29:15.051Z' AND '2024-01-17T00:30:15.051Z'  )
WHERE inverter_1.timestamp BETWEEN '2024-01-17T00:29:15.051Z' AND '2024-01-17T00:30:15.051Z'
SAMPLE BY 1s;
```